# Is Shadow DOM able to secure elements?

Tags: security, dom, widget, web-component, shadow-dom

### Goal: an encapculated widget

Suppose I'm the developer of a widget showing a list of friends, such as:

> *Your friends Michael, Anna and Shirley love this webpage!*

### First approach: script that creates `span`

Naively, I create a script which places this information in a `span` on the website. However, the owners of ExampleSite can now access the names of your friends by simple DOM operations!

That's a big **privacy / security** issue.

### Second approach: an `iframe`

I don't want ExampleSite to have access to their friends' names. So instead, I let website owners add the widget with an `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="http://fakebook.com/friends?page=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F"></iframe>
```

This works, because the owners of ExampleSite cannot scrape the contents of the `iframe`. However, this whole `iframe` thing is rather ugly, because it **does not integrate** into the styling of the website, while a `span` does.

### Desired approach: Shadow DOM

When reading about [Shadow Dom](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) yesterday, I wondered whether that could be a solution to both issues. It would allow me to have a script that creates a `span` the original website cannot access:

```
var host = document.querySelector('#friends');
var root = host.webkitCreateShadowRoot();
root.textContent = 'Your friends Michael, Anna and Shirley love this webpage!';
```

However, **does a Shadow DOM hide its contents from the surrounding page?**

The assumption here is that nobody except my script can access `root`, but is that correct?

The [Shadow DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) after all says that it offers *functional encapsulation*, but I actually want *trust encapsulation*. And while the Component Model Use Cases actually list [this use case](http://www.w3.org/2008/webapps/wiki/Component_Model_Use_Cases#Like.2F.2B1_Button), I'm not sure whether Shadow DOM realizes the necessary *confinement* property.

Comment: “However, this whole `iframe` thing is rather ugly, because it does not integrate into the styling of the website, while a `span` does.” [`<iframe seamless>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-seamless) solves this.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on an API "that [is] not yet fully standardized and still in flux". I would just use a frame that lets them pass in some basic styles (background-color, color, etc.)

Comment: @MathiasBynens `seamless` seems interesting. What's browser support?

Comment: @WaleedKhan I didn't say it's something I need implemented tomorrow. I just wonder whether Shadow DOM offers this kind of security.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh [WebKit has (at least some level of) `seamless` support](http://peter.sh/2013/01/animatable-pseudo-elements-seamless-iframe-fixes-and-happy-2013/). As far as I know no other browser engines do, but then again I haven’t tested this.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Will the `seamless` attribute have an effect if the iframe's content is from another domain?!

Comment: Unfortunately, the seamless attribute support is [non-existent](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless) after Chrome [dropped it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229421).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not, but it's in the works: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=20144

The encapsulation of trust will involve creating a new scripting context for each shadow tree, which is overkill for most scenarios. However, as the bug says, we'll add a flag (details TBD) that would allow this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's no information on the net that explicitly points to that fact, that this feature is planned. For other readers: I've found a discussion about the isolation types on the public webapps mailing list http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014JanMar/thread.html#msg217

Comment: This answer by a WebKit contributor may be of interest: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/100#issuecomment-161867941