# Is a Closed Shadow DOM within Content Script Secure?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338817/can-a-shadow-dom-secure-my-elements) question but specifically for a content script.

[This](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#closed) article talks about there being a false sense of security when using closed mode because "There's nothing stopping an attacker from hijacking Element.prototype.attachShadow."

However, [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) article talks about content scripts being run in isolated environments.

Is it therefore safe to assume that any shadow DOM attached via a content script is secure?

Comment: No. What if another extension changes `Element.prototype.attachShadow`?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Extensions are isolated from each other, too.

Comment: Yes. But because multiple roots have been removed, this may break things occasionally if the site also tries to add a shadow root.

Comment: Secure against what? What's your threat model? Extensions can definitely pierce the shadow dom. The untrusted page probably not, but the API surface is huge, so it's difficult to say for sure (shadow dom + iframe does sound safer).